# How do you apply a class's style with setAttribute inside a class that extends HTMLElement?

Tags: javascript, css, class, extends, classname

I have a class that I add an  element with a class name that should make the text white which I have defined in my CSS's style, but it does not. The text remains black. How am I supposed to achieve this other than setting the element's CSS manually?

```js
class TestClass extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    var shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });

    var title = document.createElement('h5');
    title.setAttribute('class', 'whiteText');
    title.innerText = "Test text"
    shadow.appendChild(title);
  }
}
customElements.define('test-el', TestClass);
var container = document.getElementById("container")
container.innerHTML = ""
container.appendChild(new TestClass());
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
}

.whiteText {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `h5` element to the shadow dom so the style is not applied.

To apply the style, it is needed to define independent `<style>` tag inside shadow dom as follows.

```js
class TestClass extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    var shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    var title = document.createElement('h5');
    title.setAttribute('class', 'whiteText');
    title.innerText = "Test text"
    shadow.appendChild(title);
    
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = '.whiteText { font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; color: white; }';
    shadow.appendChild(style);
  }
}
customElements.define('test-el', TestClass);
var container = document.getElementById("container")
container.innerHTML = ""
container.appendChild(new TestClass());
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your CSS.

```
body { 
  background-color:black;
  margin: 0; 
}
.whiteText {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:white;
}
```

add to add class, this is easier way

```
title.classList.add("whiteText");
// or
title.classList.toggle("whiteText");
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that, but it still doesn't solve the issue.